# Proving a relation between Fourier coefficients and the number $n$ of the partitions of a function on an interval

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, fourier-analysis

Let

$$f_n(t)=\sum_{j=1}^n \chi_{A_j}(t)$$

be a piecewise continuous function, where $A_j(t)=(t_j-t_{j-1})$ is the indicator function.  A picture of the intervals of the indicator functions are given here, in terms of $\xi$ (Xi on the image) instead of $t$:

[image]

Also, a picture of such a function is:
[image]

Now, let the Fourier series of the function be given by:

$$f_n(t)=\frac{\alpha_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k\cos\omega k t+\beta_k\sin\omega kt $$

Let us consider the $j^{th}$ *indicator* function. Here its coefficients are, where $\chi$ is the respective value of *f(t)* on the specific  interval of the $j^{th}$ indicator function:

\begin{equation}
    \alpha_0^j=\frac{1}{a}\int_{-a}^a\chi_{A_j}(t)\text{d}t
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \alpha_k^j=\frac{1}{a}\int_{-a}^a\chi_{A_j}(t)\cos\bigg(\frac{\pi k}{a}t\bigg)\text{d}t
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \beta_k^j=\frac{1}{a}\int_{-a}^a\chi_{A_j}(t)\sin\bigg(\frac{\pi k}{a}t\bigg)\text{d}t
\end{equation}

Here comes the major clue:
The number of intervals of the piece-wise function, dividing (-a,a), which is $n$ (at the top), are related to the number of the given Fourier coefficients.

So if $n=4$, then we should have 4 coefficient for each type, so $\{\alpha_0^1, \alpha_0^2, \alpha_0^3, \alpha_0^4\}$, and $\{\alpha_k^1, \alpha_k^2, \alpha_k^3, \alpha_k^4\}$
and $\{\beta_k^1, \beta_k^2, \beta_k^3, \beta_k^4\}$.

Ok, that is fine. 4 indicator functions make up the piecewise function, and give 4 coefficients of each of the three types given above. If we sum these four coefficient together, then we get the whole coefficient for the entire piecewise function at the top.

But at this stage I should prove that we can uniquely determine the piece-wise constant function   (numbers for $\chi_j, \ j=1,2,\cdots, n $) on a given grid of points $t_j, \ j=0,1,\cdots, n $ solely from the coefficients. This means in other words that we can find $\chi_1$ from $\alpha_0^1$ for instance, or $\chi_2$ from $\alpha_k^2$ for that matter.

But where should I start?

Any hints are appreciated

Thanks

Comment: When you say $A_j(t)=(t_j-t_{j-1})$ is the indicator function, do you mean that $A_j(t)$ is the indicator function on the open interval $(t_{j-1}, t_j)$? Or something else?

Comment: Do the $t_j$'s form an ascending sequence of numbers between $-a$ and $a$? I'm having trouble understanding what is this piecewise continuous function.

Comment: @KennyWong yes to both your questions. I attach an update. See picture inlay of the OP

Comment: Is there an explanation of what are the $\eta$? Perhaps they are the endpoints?  Or the widths? Or the centers of the intervals?

Comment: @MathWonk sorry for not specifying that. The $\eta_j$ are the same for $\chi$ as the $t_j$ are for $t$. I renamed them to $\chi_j$

Comment: Are the indicator function intervals  known to be non-overlapping?  Is the set of grid points $t_j$ known in advance? What features of the characteristic functions do you want to recover? (Is it just the total number, or something more refined like their endpoints etc.)

Comment: @MathWonk The indicator functions overlap, such that the piecewise function becomes continuous on $[-a,a]$ . I would like to recover only $\chi_j$ from one of the  coefficients $\alpha_{0}^j$, $\alpha_{k}^j$ or $\beta_{k}^j$.

Comment: Can you sketch a graph of a typical $f(t)$ to clarify matters?

Comment: @MathWonk, done